# ZeroMQ pub-sub categories: are wild cards possible for multiple subscriptions?

Tags: zeromq, publish-subscribe

I have been reading through the ZeroMQ documentation and I was wondering if there is a way to subscribe using wild cards? I need a system where you can publish on something like A.B.C and then subscribe on A.`*`.C or A.B.`*` ( i.e. a subscription on A.`*`.C will match publications on A.B.C, A.X.C, A.Y.C, etc ).

Answer (score 1):

### Directly? No.
Indirectly? Oh, sure, Sir!

ZeroMQ syntax for `.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, ... )` method, per-se, does not permit to setup other but prefix-matched topic-filter subscriptions. Technology used inside the filtering does not permit a more complex string/parsing, due to performance reasons mentioned many times by both Martin SUSTRIK and Pieter HINTJENS.

A funny thing comes as side-effect from this - one cannot avoid expanded strings, that go "beyond" the topic-filter length, from positively matching and thus from being delivered.

This does not mean, we shall give up. ZeroMQ is known to operate on indeed many thousands items, so let's harness this side of the magic.

### How to setup a filter like `"A.*.C"`?

One approach could be to use a rather naive ( mild ) force and "mechanically" setup all the possible "expansions" of the formal filter "A.*.C" - i.e.:

```
for aWildcardToEXPAND_item in ( "A", "B", "C", "D", ... ): # all legal expansions
    aSUB.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "A.{0:%s}.C".format( aWildcardToEXPAND_item ) )
pass; # just-SEQ life is great & so forgiving :o)
```

Many way smarter, decorated, context-of-use specialised iterators may help in extending this into easy setup/discard expansion/subscription iterators, that will match all your needs, so do not hesitate to go forwards, it is doable.

Answer (score 0):

ZeroMQ `PUB/SUB` does a prefix matching. So A.B.* is fine ( will match A.B.C in your example ).
"Inplace matching" is not supported, for obvious reasons ( subscriptions are stored in a trie data structure ) [http://www.250bpm.com/blog:19]

Comment: ZeroMQ does not seem to support category or type based subscriptions, only content based. The link provided to [http://www.250bpm.com](http://www.250bpm.com) was not useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to "" in an in process zmq socket and then implement more advanced filter there as a proxied thread of execution that advertises the actual XPUB socket that receives requests to perform filtering.